# better way to design loop

Tags: java, loops

I am wondering is there any better way to design loops. AS you see function1 and function2 has almost similar code expect getting Hash Map.

**Current Code 1 **

```
//Field
 ResultSet rs = null;
 HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap1;
 HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap2;



if(somecondition)
{
   function1()
}
else
{
   function2();
}

void function1()
{
    while(rs.next)
    {
       hashMap1 = someClass.getData1();
       hashMap2 = someClass.getData2();
       // compareHashMap
   }

}

void function2()
{
    while(rs.next)
    {
       hashMap1 = someClass.getModfiedData1();
       hashMap2 = someClass.getModfiedData2(); 
        // compareHashMap
    }
 }
```

**Another Way( short and sweet) 2**

```
while(rs.next)
{
     if(somecondition)
     {
         hashMap1 = someClass.getData1();
         hashMap2 = someClass.getData2();
     }
     else
     {
       hashMap1 = someClass.getModfiedData1();
       hashMap2 = someClass.getModfiedData2();  
     }
     // compareHashMap
 }
```

**Questions:**

If there are 10000 records or more in DB is it better to go with 1 ?

Is there any alternate desgin or I go wiht No 2?

Thanks

Comment: These kinds of operations are usually related to operations like `filter`, `transform`, `zip`, `reduce`, etc. Guava implements most of these, and the resulting code would look quite pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in the first example, you check a condition once and then iterate over N records.  In example 2, you are iterating over N records as well as performing N condition checks.  If this is a condition that needs to be examined for each individual record, then the second loop is the one to be used.  Otherwise if it is a condition that only needs to be checked once...why add the unneeded overhead of checking the condition N times?

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier way would be to make "somecondition" a property that you set on someClass, and then have a single method that you call to getthe data. Something like

```
someClass.someCondition = somecondition

while(rs.next)
{
    hashMap1 = someClass.getMyData1();
    hashMap2 = someClass.getMyData2();
}
```

or, you could pass the variable into the function

```
while(rs.next)
{
    hashMap1 = someClass.getMyData1(somecondition);
    hashMap2 = someClass.getMyData2(somecondition);
}
```